# Why is this move illegal?

Tags: 3d-chess

I'm trying to learn 3-D chess by playing [Parmen](http://www.parmen.com/) against the computer.  I've read the [tournament rules](http://home.arcor.de/jens.meder/3dschach/chess3d.htm) and am fairly confident I've got a good, basic understanding of the game.  However, in my first game, I've quickly encountered a situation where the program is telling me I'm trying to make an illegal move which I think would be legal.

The moves so far (I'm playing white):

> 1. a4N, Nc6N
> 2. c4N, Nb6N
> 3. Nb3N, Nxc4N
> 4. d3N, N4a5B

The move I'd like to make now is `Nxa5B`, but I'm alerted that it is an illegal move.  Can someone explain to me why this is?

Comment: @Iszi, would you mind using the full notation, and perhaps showing an image of the board (with the rank and files) showing the board position just before the illegal move?

Comment: @user1873 The notation above is the same notation that is output by Parmen and, according to my understanding, is in alignment with the notation used in tournament rules.  Getting a solid screenshot that effectively shows the position of all the pieces on all levels of the board is a bit tricky.

Comment: Also, I've quit the game in question and am not sure if I can reliably reproduce it with this particular software.

Comment: Just a display of the screen?

Comment: @chac Firstly, I'm not currently familiar with how or if I could reproduce the game progression since I've closed the game without saving it.  Even if I could, I'm currently experiencing some crashes in the game.  See this thread on [gaming.se] for more details:  http://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/52333/6274  Also, as I've already said, getting a good screenshot that effectively shows all the pieces on the board is very difficult due to the three-dimensional nature of the game and two-dimensional nature of screen captures.

Answer (score 3):

Your King is in check from your opponent's Queen.

Comment: While I can't put together a visual representation to check this at the moment, this does sound about right now that I think about it.  It probably never occurred to me before, because I'm so accustomed to the King & Queen being in the center of their row.

Comment: @Iszi, I am considering putting a visual together myself. I had to look back and forth at the Tournament Rules with the board visual and your move list to try to see the board in my mind.

Comment: Well, drat.  I was going to attempt reproducing this in Parmen tonight, but now the program's going all crashy on me.